# Pgfplots and Adobe Reader DC

Tags: pgfplots, adobe

I am trying to build interactive plots using package `pgfplots`.
I have downloaded from the package page some of the examples with the
clickable option, I have compiled them with pdflatex but I have problems
when opening the pdf file with Adobe reader DC. For example, compiling
`example_9.tex` (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/example_9.tex), when I click on any of the points in the pdf file, the graph becomes all blue and nothing else happens. I have tried to open the file with a previous version of Adobe Reader (XI) and it all works fine.
In the Adobe Reader DC console for Javascript debug, I have these errors:

```
    SyntaxError: super is a reserved identifier
    217:Document-Level:01 pgfplots Clickable Plot Code
```

when I open the file and

```
    ReferenceError: axisMouseDown is not defined
    1:Field:Mouse Down
    ReferenceError: axisMouseUp is not defined
    1:Field:Mouse Up
```

when I click on any of the points on the graph.
Does someone have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to an incompatibility in the document level javascript code generated by the `clickable` lib. I resolved and repaired it; the issue will be gone in future versions.

The only workaround appears to be

- decompress the resulting pdf files
- replace the string `super` in the argument list of function `PGFPlotsClassExtend` by something else (for example `supre` which has the same string length).

This has not been tested, though.